# How to start/stop a script at specific time?

Tags: python-2.7

I have writen a script that reads at real time a log file. The problem I have got is that the location of that logfile changes every midnight, same filename diferent folder.

I can regenerate the file location path but I don't know how to start/stop the script to reprocess the log file? Right now I am doing it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be

```
(a) If it's a linux box, why not run a "cron" job (which will stop and start the script)
(b) Alternatively, in your code, detect when the file can no longer be read, then switch folders
```

Comment: Thanks for your aswer.

(a) unofrtunatedly I am not allowed to use cron in the machine the script is running.
(b) The file can still be read. The creation of the new file does not destroy the older one.

I was thinking about detecting the time, stop for a few seconds and restart but I think It is quite dirty.

Comment: Actually you could put your code in a loop (sleep()) state; and when 00:00 comes as you say, then switch over to new file. An alternate method might be to use MD5 checksum's along with time, to allow you to determine when to run with another permutation.

Comment: This might help as well seeing that you can't use cron; http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/index.html